# Two level nesting of a class in ruby.

Tags: ruby

```
module M1
    class A
        def fun
            puts "module M1 class A method fun()"
        end
    end
end

module M2
    class A
        def fun
            puts "module M2 class A method fun()"
        end
    end
end

class MyClass
    include M1
    include M2
end

obj1 = MyClass::M1::A.new
puts obj1.class
puts obj1.object_id
obj1.fun

obj2 = MyClass::M2::A.new
puts obj2.class
puts obj2.object_id
obj2.fun
```

Output is

```
r20.rb:22: warning: toplevel constant M1 referenced by MyClass::M1
M1::A
13996360
module M1 class A method fun()
r20.rb:27: warning: toplevel constant M2 referenced by MyClass::M2
M2::A
13996120
module M2 class A method fun()
```

I can't understand why this warning message is coming.
Please expalin.
Is it a bad practice to do nesting this way if there is any such nessasity?

And one more problem is that when i call superclass method on both objects i.e Obj1 and Obj2 , no method error is coming, don't know why, I mean afterall they are also objects how come they don't have superclass method which all objects have.

Comment: You're calling superclass method where?

Comment: Also, what is this "necessity" of including nested classes like this? It's not idiomatic at all.

Comment: outside all the definitions, after instantiating obj1 and obj2

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - if i need to include two classes in a class  but they have a  method of same name , then how do i resolve that.

Comment: Why do you need to include _classes_ in a class?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - for polymorphism...but i think it gets me stuck in diamond inheritance type of problem

Comment: You're confusing polymorphism and multiple inheritance, it seems. Former is good, latter - not so much. And yeah, don't do MI :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - ok  i'll not do that in practical applications.Actually i started learning Ruby so was just tweaking the possibilities.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev What’s wrong with inclusion classes in classes? Don’t muddle OP, including classes makes sense sometimes, OP just referenced the included not properly (see my answer for details.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually ruby prints the sufficient enough message to understand, what’s going on.

First of all, this is how your code is to be re-written to get no warnings:

```
- obj1 = MyClass::M1::A.new
+ obj1 = M1::A.new
```

This is probably not what you wanted, but this is what you instructed ruby to do.

#### Why?

It’s simple. Modules and class names are constants in ruby. By

```
include M1
```

you ***virtually inline*** (not exactly, but the difference is out of scope of this question) ***the content*** of `M1` into your `MyClass`.

After you have the content of `M1` inlined, you reference it by

```
MyClass::M1
```

but wait! `M1` constant is already defined on `Object` (top level). And `MyClass` is derived from `Object` as any other user-produced class in ruby by default. The try to reference constant `Object::M1` as it was belonging to `MyClass` namespace produces a warning.

#### What is created?

The `MyClass::M1::A` is actually an incorrect, but working synonym for `M1::A`. `MyClass::A` was *redefined* by second `include`. So, you:

- instantiated two different classes `M1::A` and `M2::A`, both having *nothing to do* with `MyClass`;
- have yourself entangled, possibly assuming that you now have `MyClass` namespaced classes `M1::A` and `M2::A`;
- have actually ***one*** `MyClass::A` class, with `fun` function that came from `M2`, since the `MyClass::A` class is opened (see “[opened classes in ruby](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=opened+classes+in+ruby&t=canonical)”) and `MyClass::A#fun` definition was *monkeypatched* by the second include statement.

#### How to GTD?

Since `include` in fact inlines content, this is how you could achieve the behaviour you were likely wanting to achieve:

```
module MM
  module M1
    class A
        def fun ; puts "module M1 class A method fun()" ; end
    end 
  end 

  module M2
    class A
        def fun ; puts "module M2 class A method fun()" ; end
    end 
  end 
end

class MyClass
    include MM
end

obj1 = MyClass::M1::A.new
puts obj1.class
puts obj1.object_id
obj1.fun

obj2 = MyClass::M2::A.new
puts obj2.class
puts obj2.object_id
obj2.fun

#⇒ MM::M1::A
#⇒ 100355060
#⇒ module M1 class A method fun()
#⇒ MM::M2::A
#⇒ 100354990
#⇒ module M2 class A method fun()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i got it and need to read more of metaprogramming. can u suggest a good reference for reading about polymorphism in ruby?

Comment: Glad to help. You could [start here](http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/html/ruby_metaprogramming_1.html). After all, Matz wrone an excellent book about ruby in a nutshell: “The Ruby Programming Language ISBN 0-596-51617-7” by Yukihiro Matsumoto.